# Flutter: how can I trace the 'print' line?

Tags: flutter

```
I/flutter ( 6499): fliter clicked
I/ViewRootImpl@c5d3a59[MainActivity]( 6499): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c5d3a59[MainActivity]( 6499): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@c5d3a59[MainActivity]( 6499): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c5d3a59[MainActivity]( 6499): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter ( 6499): Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'RxInt'
```

I am trying to find which .dart and command line is is printing on this (6499) case. I'm using the VScode and is there any way that I can trace this down?

Comment: You can always **CTRL+F** and search for the **print** keyword in your code

Comment: @chichi Did you find where it comes from? If yes which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple do `CTRL+SHIFT+F` and search for `print` or `debugPrint()` whichever you used

Comment: This is not helpful when you try to pin-point a warning that was generated by Flutter itself.